# PyTorch element-wise product of vectors / matrices / tensors

Tags: matrix, vector, pytorch, tensor

In PyTorch, how do I get the [element-wise product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of two vectors / matrices / tensors?

For googlers, this is product is also known as:

- Hadamard product
- Schur product
- Entrywise product

Answer (score 55):

Given two tensors `A` and `B` you can use either:

- `A * B`
- [`torch.mul(A, B)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mul.html#torch-mul)
- `A.mul(B)`

**Note**: for *matrix multiplication*, you want to use `A @ B` which is equivalent to [`torch.matmul()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html#torch-matmul).

Comment: -2 Downvotes... why? Please give me constructive feedback to improve :)